# How to change variable in python file using an executable linux program/script?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I am building a datalogger for a group of PV inverters using Raspberry Pi and am using two python scripts to collect the data over two separate communication protocols. I need to change two variables in each script if I move from one site to another - the first and the last inverter id for the new site.
I want to make this change user friendly such that a new user does not have to open the python script to change the values. So I want to have an executable program in linux environment (which may have an icon on the Pi desktop) which the user can open and it will prompt to specify first and last inverter id and transfers this change to python script. If this is too complicated to achieve for this task, maybe a simple command for the terminal window which will prompt the same changes??

I hope the task is sufficiently explained. I am not a programmer by trade and am doing this project as a hobby, so please forgive me if I am ignoring something obvious :|

Comment: The standard way to do this would probably be a configuration file. Is there some reason that approach wouldn't work for you?

Comment: do you need to change the variable while the script is runnning or maybe you need it just before starting the script?

Comment: You can use system arguments with `sys.argv`. This should allow user to run your script from Terminal as `python script.py firstId lastId`

Comment: that's what I was thinking. And maybe you can make it more user friendly by creating a launcher on the Pi Desktop

Comment: I don't use Raspberry Pi, but I see that it's pretty easy to [create a desktop config file](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/gui/desktop-shortcuts) to run a script via a desktop shortcut icon. And I assume that the user can easily edit the commandline args of the script; in many environments you can do that from the context menu that pops up when you right-click the shortcut icon.

Comment: yes I need to change the variables before the script starts running. Could you explain a bit or give link for creating a launcher on Pi?
The script is later invoked from cron jobs to ensure it is always up, so I dont want to do it as @Andersson has mentioned since the user will have to go inside cron jobs and change it there as well. Or is there a way to just specify 'firstId','lastId' values elsewhere so that I can permanently add just instances of those in the crontab?

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks! this looks exactly like what I was trying to do. I will try doing this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting a successful update for this query. The desktop configuration file method was the simplest and it worked. I wrote the following in the .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name= ProgramName
Comment= my comment
Exec=sudo python /usr/share/app/app.py
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/geany.xpm
Path=/usr/local/lib/python2.7
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

I added the "python" bit to the Exec line and hence did not have to write a she-bang line in the script. Also the Terminal option had to made True since I needed a prompt for the user to enter a value.

Hope this helps somebody else.